# My DeflaterOutputStream/InputStream code corrupting data

Tags: java, stream, compression

I've got a simple test case that fails to compress a stream of data.  I generate a `byte[]` of some random bytes, compress it via `DeflaterOutputStream`, `flush()` the stream, then reverse those operations to retrieve the original array.  At byte 505 the reconstructed stream starts to consist entirely of `0x00` bytes, and I don't understand why:

```java
        //
        // create some random bytes
        //
        Random rng = new Random();
        int len = 5000;
        byte[] data = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            data[i] = (byte) rng.nextInt(0xff);

        //
        // write to byte[] via a deflater stream
        //
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DeflaterOutputStream os = new DeflaterOutputStream(baos, true);
        os.write(data);
        os.flush();

        //
        // read back into byte[] via an inflater stream
        //
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        InflaterInputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(bais);
        byte[] readbytes = new byte[len];
        is.read(readbytes);

        //
        // check they match (they don't, at byte 505)
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
            if (data[i] != readbytes[i])
                throw new RuntimeException("Mismatch at position " + i);
```

It doesn't seem to matter what's in the source array, it's always at position 505 it fails.

Here's what the two `byte[]` arrays look like around the region they differ:

```
?\m·g··gWNLErZ···,··-··=·;n=··F?···13·{·rw·······\`3···f····{/····t·1·WK$·······WZ······x
?\m·g··gWNLErZ···,··-····································································
                       ^byte 505
```

All those unprintable chars are `0x00` from that point on.  Why is this happening?  I feel like I must be misunderstanding something fundamental about how the Deflate/Inflate streams work.  The real-world use case here is a stream over a network that I thought I could easily improve the performance of by inserting Deflate/Inflate streams into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test this, `is.read(readBytes)` returns 505, the length of bytes read.  The other single-argument-array stream methods return `void` and guarantee that the entire array is read or written, but `is.read()` is a different API and requires that you check the amount of bytes actually read.

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    System.err.println( "bais size = " + bais.available() );
    InflaterInputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(bais);
    byte[] readbytes = new byte[len];
    System.err.println( "read = " + is.read(readbytes) );  // 505
```

This runs without throwing an error for me:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
    System.err.println( "bais size = " + bais.available() );
    InflaterInputStream is = new InflaterInputStream(bais);
    byte[] readbytes = new byte[len];
    for( int total = 0, result = 0; (result = is.read(readbytes, total, len-total )) != -1; )
    {
       total += result;
       System.err.println( "reading : " + total );
       if( total == len ) break;
    }
```